# How to remove multiple value in firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase

[image: issue screenshot]

how to remove multiple firebase nodes on onclick in andorid?

Comment: Do you need to remove all children below the `Area` node? Or only three of them?

Comment: only three them

Comment: How many items are in total?

Comment: near 25 somthing

Comment: And you only want to delete the first three, right?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a Firebase database like this

```
sample_database-d03f
   |
   |___animals
          |____ cat : "Mike"
          |____ dog : "trey"
          |____ monkey : "Jazz"
          |____ Hippo : "Thomas"
          |____ Lion : "Simba"
```

And you want to remove {cat , monkey , lion} from animals, which in this case are stored in an Array

```
String[] AnimalsToRemove = new String[] {"cat","monkey","lion"};
```

We will have to iterate through the animals we want to remove, and for each animal we remove it from the database like this

```
//Database Reference
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

//removing values
for (String animal : AnimalsToRemove) {
      //remove the value from Firebase DB
      mDatabase.child("animals").child(animal).removeValue();
}
```